# rendered video tracking isn't the same as in 3D view

Tags: tracking

I am really new to blender I was following a tutorial to put a mask on my face.
I put dots on my face and tracked it very good (Solve error 0.3391).
After that I put a mask on my face and the mask was moving when my face is moving. 
So far every thing is good, but when I start rendering I got these issues:

1. mask shows ghostly
2. the colors looks different

[image]

Sorry that I can't provide pictures of my face with the mask.

I had another error that the dots I tracked on my face on the movie view.
It's not on the same place when I go to the 3d view
(the dots in the 3d view aren't on my face, and the camera isn't facing my fill face for some reason) .

[image]

I had to move the mask under the dots so it will be on my face.

total probs 2 
tracking dots no showing on my face on 3d view mode 
rendering ghostly objects with high contract colors